# Is there a verb for singing nonsense syllables to substitute for unknown lyrics?

Tags: single-word-requests, music

Someone who doesn't know all the lyrics to a song might sing "la la la" or "dum dum dum" in place of the verses they don't know.  Is there a verb for this?  Similar to "humming" the tune, but with syllables?

I'm aware of the verb "scat," but to me it implies a particular style of fast-paced jazz nonsense vocalization.  I'm looking for a more general word, if it exists.

Comment: Not a verb, but those types of nonsense syllables are sometimes called "filler", so you could say you "substitute filler for the unknown lyrics." Or something along those lines.

Comment: Humming doesn't preclude syllables; someone who is ‘humming a tune’ while vacuuming, for instance, may well actually be hmmhmhm-dumdadadee-bmdmdadoo’ing more than just hmmmmmmmm’ing. Then again, if it's an actual part of a song (as in the well-known riff from _Tom’s Diner_, or indeed the entire album entitled _( )_ by the Icelandic band Sigur Rós), then it's definitely not humming anymore.

Comment: Checking the definition of humming, it means "to sing with closed lips," so I don't think it quite fits.  If the nonsense is an actual part of the song, I think it's called a "vocalise" (http://english.stackexchange.com/a/206944/9601).

Comment: Perhaps *non-lexical vocable*, but it is not specific to substituting for unknown lyrics.

Answer (score 2):

You can say *fudge the lyrics.*

Example of [authentic use](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/archive/index.php/t-280527.html):

> I discovered recently that there's a line that goes "Just your typical prototype." I usually **fudged my way through the lyrics** with something having to do with keeping kimonos tied, and wondered why the hell her bathrobe had anything to do with it.

Instrumentalists do this too, but then it's called *faking it*.  You have to do that in certain passages of the last movement of Tchaikovsky's Fourth Symphony.

Answer (score 0):

If you honestly mishear the lyrics then, [mondegreen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen) could work. You'd have to mistake actual lyrics for la la la or dum dum dum.

Of course its a noun, so I guess it wouldn't work. I don't think there are any single words for what your thinking of though.

Comment: Interesting word, but the question didn't say anything about mishearing the lyrics.

Comment: Yeah, I've got a little to used to quora